# Expand and collapse a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Here http://dev.arphilvolis.fr/ at section L'avis des professionnels on Lire la suite click i need to expand a div and on another click collaps the div.

My HTML structure :

```
<p style="text-align: left;">some content here</p>
<p style="text-align: left;">some content here</p>
<span class="collapslink">Lire la suite</span>
<div class="collapscontent">
    <p style="text-align: left;">content</p>
    <p style="text-align: left;">content</p>
</div>
```

My jQuery code :

```
jQuery(".collapslink").click(function() {

    $collapslink = $(this);

    //getting the next element
    $collapscontent = $collapslink.next();

    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $collapscontent.slideToggle(500, function () {

        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $collapslink.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $collapscontent.is(":visible") ? "Fermer" : "Lire la suite";
        });

    });
});
```

The JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/94150148/vfcau364/20/ is working but don't on my website : http://dev.arphilvolis.fr/

Comment: The text "L'avis des professionnels" on your website is not a clickable link.

Comment: @Utkanos Yes it's normal.

Comment: Try to remove all js plugins and only add your main. Also, in your click function

jQuery(".collapslink").click(function() {

Add a console log, it doesn't seem to go in that function when I use the event listener breakpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button handler event in your live website is *outside* the `$(document).ready()`. Because your handler isn't waiting for the page to load, the `<span>` you're trying to attach it to doesn't yet exist. The handler gets attached to *nothing*.

For your handler to be attached properly, it needs to be *inside* the `jQuery(document).ready(function() { .... });`

---

**Snippet from your site demonstrating the issue:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    new Slideshowck(...);
}); 

var ampzSettings = {...};

//YOUR CODE HERE, OUTSIDE DOCUMENT READY HANDLER
jQuery(".collapslink").click(function() {

    $collapslink = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $collapscontent = $collapslink.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $collapscontent.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $collapslink.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $collapscontent.is(":visible") ? "Fermer" : "Lire la suite";
        });
    });

});

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(window).scroll(...);
});
```

---

**The fix:**

Not only is your handler not in the document ready, you're actually using two separate page load handlers. Consolidate it and you should be all set: 
*(Please note that I've collapsed your large functions/variable declarations for sake of brevity.)*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  new Slideshowck(...);          //Reduced these declarations
  jQuery(window).scroll(...);    //to take up less space
  var ampzSettings = {...};      //in the answer

  //Moved inside the document ready handler
  jQuery(".collapslink").click(function() {

    $collapslink = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $collapscontent = $collapslink.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $collapscontent.slideToggle(500, function() {
      //execute this after slideToggle is done
      //change text of header based on visibility of content div
      $collapslink.text(function() {
        //change text based on condition
        return $collapscontent.is(":visible") ? "Fermer" : "Lire la suite";
      });
    });

  });

});
```

It likely worked on JSFiddle because by default, JSFiddle wraps your JavaScript in a page-load handler.